# Can the iCloud email be obtained from an iPhone in Lost mode?

Tags: iphone, icloud, email

Basically I am very worried because my wife lost her phone 1 week ago. However, few days ago she got an email from a person saying that they had found it.

At first, we were happy because this person seemed willing to find the owner so they can return the iPhone. So, we went to FedEx and got a pre-paid shipping label for this person, so all they'd need to do is drop the phone in any FedEx store.

However days have passed and this person hasn't returned the iPhone.

So, now my head is overthinking many things about this problem and specially about the following:

**One thing I hadn't think about is, how did they get my wife's iCloud email address in the first place? At the beginning I thought it was some information the iPhone displayed on screen when the phone was put on Lost mode (which we did), but we just saw some images online and it seems all it shows is a message like "This phone is lost, please call 123-45..."**

So, we are very worried about this and the true intentions of this person.

Could anyone please help me understand how did they get our iCloud email address? Did they just unblocked my wife's phone? Should we be more worried?

Thanks!

Comment: Can't answer your question but:
1) Do not remove the iPhone from Find My iPhone - if you do, it de-registers activation lock 2) (Hopefully obvious...) don't provide your password to them. If they want to steal your phone, they will need your password to de-register activation lock.

Answer (score 3):

The Lost Mode message is whatever you typed at the time. There's no fixed format, just a suggestion.
If you only have one phone number, but access to your email from elsewhere, then it would make sense to add your email address.

I guess it's a case of trying to remember exactly what message you put in there.

I actually have my partner's phone number embedded in my lock screen picture - but that's more for emergency than if I lose it. At the scene of an accident, even in the hands of someone who has no idea how to access the emergency mode on an iPhone, they can immediately see an ICE contact just by lifting the phone to wake the screen.

[Apple KB - Mark a device as lost in Find My on iPhone](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/iph7cc193cfc/ios)

Comment: thank you for your reply. I do remember what message we put in there, it was something like "This phone is lost, please call 123-45...", so, I can't understand how this person was able to get my wife's iCloud email address.

Comment: They couldn't get it from the phone unless they knew the passcode.